# Hibernate pagination ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, pagination, ora-00918

When hibernate tries to paginate an entity generated using the following hbm.xml, it throws up column ambiguously defined.

```
<class lazy="false" dynamic-update="true" optimistic-lock="all" table="A" name="org.package.Entity">
  <cache usage="read-write"/>
  <id unsaved-value="null" type="java.lang.Long" name="aId">
    <column name="ID_A" not-null="true" sql-type="java.lang.Long"/>
    <generator class="org.package.Entity"/>
  </id>
  <property type="java.lang.Long" name="aGroupId" not-null="true">
    <column name="ID_GROUP" not-null="true" sql-type="java.lang.Long"/>
  </property>
  <property type="java.lang.String" name="statusCode" not-null="true">
    <column name="CD_STATUS" not-null="true" sql-type="char(30)" length="30"/>
  </property>
  <property type="java.lang.Long" name="templateId" not-null="false">
    <column name="ID_TEMPLATE" not-null="false" sql-type="java.lang.Long"/>
  </property>

  <many-to-one name="aGroup" cascade="none" column="Id_Group" 
      class="org.package.Entity"
      insert="false" update="false"/>
  <many-to-one name="template" cascade="none" column="ID_TEMPLATE" 
      class="org.package.Entity"
      insert="false" update="false"/>
</class>
```

What is wrong with this entity definition?

Edit: Turning it into QandA format.

Comment: As it stands, this isn't a question and seems unsuitable for posting here. But it is useful info and maybe you can create a question out of this and post this as an answer to your own question?

Comment: Truly? I have ask and answer my own question in order to share a solution that I didn't find the answer to on here?

Comment: This isn't a tech wiki or cookbook kind of site, it is a QnA site. There should be a valid question. But let's see what others think too

Comment: +1 but to be honest Frans, I wasn't sure upon first reading that you were posting a solution.  Maybe re-word it a bit.

Comment: Yes, you have to post in q and a form. The reason is that questions should allow more than one answer, and questions and answers should be able to obtain votes independent from one another.

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site: threads consist of a **question** and one or more **answers** - ideally just one, accepted answer. As it stands your question is categorised as *Unanswered*, which means other Seekers after answers will ignore it in search results. So, if you genuinely want to share your insight please do it the proper way. Who knows, [you may even get a badge for doing so](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID_TEMPLATE is being condensed into one column in the query, ID_GROUP isn't.

Hibernate uses a direct string comparison to see if two properties depend on the same column. This is case sensitive, so ID_GROUP was being selected a second time as Id_Group.

Changing the cases to match, it worked.

```
<class lazy="false" dynamic-update="true" optimistic-lock="all" table="A" name="org.package.Entity">
  <cache usage="read-write"/>
  <id unsaved-value="null" type="java.lang.Long" name="aId">
    <column name="ID_A" not-null="true" sql-type="java.lang.Long"/>
    <generator class="org.package.Entity"/>
  </id>
  <property type="java.lang.Long" name="aGroupId" not-null="true">
    <column name="ID_GROUP" not-null="true" sql-type="java.lang.Long"/>
  </property>
  <property type="java.lang.String" name="statusCode" not-null="true">
    <column name="CD_STATUS" not-null="true" sql-type="char(30)" length="30"/>
  </property>
  <property type="java.lang.Long" name="templateId" not-null="false">
    <column name="ID_TEMPLATE" not-null="false" sql-type="java.lang.Long"/>
  </property>

  <many-to-one name="aGroup" cascade="none" column="ID_GROUP" 
      class="org.package.Entity"
      insert="false" update="false"/>
  <many-to-one name="template" cascade="none" column="ID_TEMPLATE" 
      class="org.package.Entity"
      insert="false" update="false"/>
</class>
```

Maintaining old code is fun. Hope this helps someone.